# whitelisted VLANs with L3 Managed Switch routing

Tags: switch, vlan, ip-routing

I have a basic setup for self-learning purposes. I'm a developer but trying to also understand the other side of IT managing networks.

I mean learning case I have a single managed L3 switch. To it are connected the following devices:

| Device Name | Device IPv4 | Subnet Mask | Switch-Port | VLAN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Server-IT | 192.168.10.2 | 255.255.255.0 | G0/1 | 10 |
| Server-HR | 192.168.11.31 | 255.255.255.0 | G0/2 | 11 |
| Printer-IT | 192.168.20.30 | 255.255.255.0 | F0/21 | 20 |
| Printer-HR | 192.168.20.31 | 255.255.255.0 | F0/22 | 20 |
| PC-IT-1 | 192.168.30.2 | 255.255.255.248 | F0/1 | 30 |
| PC-IT-2 | 192.168.30.3 | 255.255.255.248 | F0/2 | 30 |
| PC-IT-3 | 192.168.30.4 | 255.255.255.248 | F0/3 | 30 |
| PC-IT-4 | 192.168.30.5 | 255.255.255.248 | F0/4 | 30 |
| PC-HR-1 | 192.168.31.2 | 255.255.255.248 | F0/1 | 31 |
| PC-HR-2 | 192.168.31.3 | 255.255.255.248 | F0/2 | 31 |
| PC-HR-3 | 192.168.31.4 | 255.255.255.248 | F0/3 | 31 |
| PC-HR-4 | 192.168.31.5 | 255.255.255.248 | F0/4 | 31 |

The VLANs, device ports etc. are all configured correctly and operate as I expect them to. I also let all devices communicate with each other by using IP routing. That also works correctly.

Now I tried to take the next step and limiting the access to `Server-HR` only to devices from the network `192.168.31.0 /29`. I didn't find real instructions here even while researching on Cicso, or at least none that I understand. One instruction I found stated to use ACL which I tried by using:

```
config t
ip access-list extend WHITELIST
permit ip 192.168.31.0 255.255.255.248 host 192.168.11.31
```

This did not work as I missed something. I still can communicate with the `Server-HR` from all devices not only devices from `VLAN 31`. What do I miss and what do I need to do to fix  that connection filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An access list needs to be applied to a port or VLAN. You also need to specify the direction *in* or *out* - *in* is generally preferred and your only option on some devices.

A port access list is applied like this:

```
interface g1/1
ip access group WHITELIST in
exit
```

There's an implied `deny ip any any` at the end of each ACL, so make sure you've permitted everything you need before applying. Additionally, ACLs are stateless, so you need to create rules in both directions if an ACL is applied.

You should also make your ACL names more descriptive, so you don't mix up your rules.